# New iPad 9 has poor performance, free RAM is all over the map

Tags: ipad, performance, ipados

Brand new iPad 9 64G WiFi version, 35% drive space used, updated OS.

I mainly bought this for Goodnotes and Chrome -> YouTube videos.

Goodnotes was REALLY lagging.  I would have Chrome open with many tabs and Goodnotes with a few PDF books and about 8 small (5~10 page) Goodnotes notebooks with pics (screenshots) and notes from tutorials from YouTube.

I go from one Goodnotes tab to another and I can see the screen drawing the squares, even going from one to another over and over, I can STILL see the screen drawing the squares.

I unloaded Chrome, unloaded all but 3~5 tabs in Goodnotes and it STILL lags when drawing the screen.

I downloaded GPU Info to get CPU/GPU/Memory info.  The iPad 9 has 3GB RAM and I've had 1500MB ~ 150MB free while being fully unloaded (nothing running).

I rebooted (powered down) and ran NOTHING, waited about 15 min and then checked the RAM and it was 220MB free while running NOTHING.

Hours later, I test again and it's about 1150 MB free RAM.

I have no idea how to change things / tweak the settings, etc... in order to get some reasonable performance from this thing.

I get that the iPad 9 is not the iPad hotrod, and 3GB RAM is the same as the iPad 7, while other new iPads have much more RAM...  It STILL should do better than this.

I have no idea if this is a RAM issue or a graphics issue.  The iPad 9 is supposed to have good GPU performance, so I don't get the problem.

Q. is there some software I can run to determine the settings and maybe change the setting to tweak the performance?  Maybe turn some settings off.  Maybe some info about things like indexing, spotlight or auto updates or something that might effect performance?

Maybe this is just a Goodnotes issue, maybe someone knows of some way of researching this.

Tried Reddit, but that's 100% worthless for real info.

Comment: Does this only happen in GoodNotes or also in other apps (without running GoodNotes)?

Comment: I haven't noticed any performance issues with any other apps, but I only use a few other apps and not very often.  The 8-Ball pool game runs very fast and is all graphics, the Books apps reads books very quickly, YouTube and Chrome have no problems.  Even when I had GN running, the other apps seems to be doing fine.

Comment: So this might very well be an issue related to GoodNotes then.

Comment: That seems to be the case, from what I hear, they have very bad tech support, but I'm wondering if there's some way to tweak the iPad, some settings or something.  I'm also concerned about the free RAM dropping from 1130MB to 220MB while nothing is running and after shutdown.  Maybe there's some tools to dig into the iPadOS in order to see what's going on.  I have a paid Apple dev account, so I can make apps, just don't know of any API or tools to dig into these things.

Comment: iOS does a fairly good job in managing RAM *between* apps, memory management within an app is up to the app itself. So the numbers you see are not all that useful, GoodNotes gets all available memory anyway.